# How can I use adb or other utilities to query the camera list that my rom supports?

Tags: adb, camera, lineageos, android-11

I'm using LinageOS with MicroG. Is there a method to get the listing of enabled/supported cameras by the rom/firmware?

I am using Android 11.

Comment: The common Linux knowledge should help you to identify the supported webcam drivers https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/hardware.html

Comment: @Robert a phone's camera isn't a webcam.

Comment: Sorry you had not mentioned that you are planning to replace the internal camera module. Usually external webcams are the only cameras that can change on an Android system. You should edit your question and describe what you want to do, then people will better understand your question.

Comment: @Robert I'm not planning on replacing an internal camera module. I just want to know which hardware cameras on my phone my aftermarket ROM (LinageOS with MicroG) supports. There should be some way to query this with adb.

Comment: You could look into the device tree definition of your ROM. As it is LineageOS you can check the LineageOS git repos (assuming LineageOS means you are using an official release).

Comment: @Robert yeah, that's one way. While I'm interested to know more about this method too. I don't think it's a suitable answer on this question.